How does Windows handle display scaling at 150%?
I’m working on a Windows application and have a question about display scaling. If I set “Change the size of text, apps, and other items” to 150%, does Windows achieve this by effectively “shrinking” the screen resolution? For example, would a resolution of 1280 x 720 at 150% scaling be equivalent to viewing a screen with a resolution of approximately 853 x 480 (1280 * 2/3, 720 * 2/3)?
I ask because some of my users have this setting at values other than 100% (e.g., 150%), and I want my UI to look good under these conditions.
I’ve never worked with scaling before, so I’m unsure of its impact. My work laptop has this setting disabled (though it is not disabled for all users). I’m hoping that I can just design for a smaller resolution and that will suffice, but I’m concerned that this setting might have other side effects. Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated.

not sure what language you're using, but you might want to look at DPI awareness. Here is what Microsoft writes about scaling: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/high-dpi-desktop-application-development-on-windows#display-scale-factor--dpi
